# Group and summarize json data to new json object

Tags: javascript, json

I am using angularJS and have a JSON object from an API response which looks like the following:

```
var data = [
  {"group": "red", "state": "running"},
  {"group": "red", "state": "closed"},
  {"group": "red", "state": "closed"},
  {"group": "blue", "state": "running"},
  {"group": "blue", "state": "running"}
];
```

I would like to parse this object inside a javascript function to get the following result:

```
var sumdata = [
  {"group": "red", "running": 1, "closed": 2, "summary": 3},
  {"group": "blue", "running": 2, "closed": 0, "summary": 2}
];
```

So, I have to group the first property called "group", then count how many objects in this group are in running state, closed state and also summarize the count of objects.

(Note:
I would not like to use extra javascript libraries like [LINQ.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/)
)

Could yo help me please?

I tried the following, which is missing the group by and have no idea how to put that into this function:

```
var getSum = function (data) {

    if (!data) {

        $scope.data = [];
    }
    else {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            var group = data[i][0];
            var status = data[i][1];

            status = (status ? status.Name : "").toUpperCase();

            var running = 0;
            var closed = 0;

            switch (status) {

                case "RUNNING":
                    running++;
                    break;

                case "CLOSED":
                    closed++;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            var summary = running + closed;        
            $scope.dataSum.push({ "group": group, "running": running, "closed": closed, "summary": summary});
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: What have you tried? Post the code you've used so far. This generally isn't a "we write code for you" service

Comment: people are mistaking SO for a free code service... no comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a proposal with a temporary object and an [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop in plain Javascript.

```js
var data = [{ "group": "red", "state": "running" }, { "group": "red", "state": "closed" }, { "group": "red", "state": "closed" }, { "group": "blue", "state": "running" }, { "group": "blue", "state": "running" }],
    grouped = function (array) {
        var r = [];
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            if (!this[a.group]) {
                this[a.group] = { group: a.group, running: 0, closed: 0, summary: 0 };
                r.push(this[a.group]);
            }
            this[a.group][a.state]++;
            this[a.group].summary++;
        }, Object.create(null));
        return r;
    }(data);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thank you, it did the trick and was shorter then what I tried. (I extend your solution with the summary property)

Answer (score 0):

With the **LINQ** power it will look something like that:

```js
var data = [{
  "group": "red",
  "state": "running"
}, {
  "group": "red",
  "state": "closed"
}, {
  "group": "red",
  "state": "closed"
}, {
  "group": "blue",
  "state": "running"
}, {
  "group": "blue",
  "state": "running"
}];


var result = Enumerable.From(data).GroupBy('$.group', null, function(key, group) {
  return {
    group: key,
    running: group.Where(function(value) {
      return value.state == 'running'
    }).Count(),
    closed: group.Where(function(value) {
      return value.state == 'closed'
    }).Count(),
    summary: group.Where(function(value) {
      return value.state == 'running' || value.state == 'closed'
    }).Count()
  }
}).ToArray()

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
```

Comment: @NinaScholz check if you have access to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js or switch to other CDN

Comment: i have no access to cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

The below snipped works for any number of fields in the data array. You only give the name of the field you want to group by. it is better than other examples in the way that it will work for any kind of data not only named like you suggested.
Hope it help.

```
(function(){
        var data = [
                        { "group": "red", "state": "running" },
                        { "group": "red", "state": "closed" },
                        { "group": "red", "state": "closed" },
                        { "group": "blue", "state": "running" },
                        { "group": "blue", "state": "running" },
                        { "group": "blue", "state": "asd", "value":"33" },
                        { "group": "blue", "state": "asd1", "value":"33" },
                        { "group": "red", "state": "asd", "value":"33" }
        ],
        grouped = function (array) {
            var r = [];
            var groupFieldName = "group";

            array.forEach(function (a) {
                var self = this;
                if (!self[a[groupFieldName]]) {
                    var tempObj = {
                        group: a[groupFieldName]
                    };
                    self[a[groupFieldName]] = tempObj;
                    r.push(self[a[groupFieldName]]);
                }
                var keys = Object.keys(a);
                keys.forEach(function(key){
                    if(key != groupFieldName){
                        if(self[a[groupFieldName]][a[key]] == undefined){
                            self[a[groupFieldName]][a[key]] = 1;
                        }else{
                            self[a[groupFieldName]][a[key]]++;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, Object.create(null));
            return r;
        }(data);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped));

})()
```

Comment: Thank you. In my current solution I just need the 'running' and 'close' statistics which I display in a table. But as you wrote, your solution works with any kind of data which is a good point.